# making download option in grails

Tags: html, grails, gsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grails File Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396677/grails-file-download)

I am in the training of web developement.I want make a page which shows all the files in the D://downloads directory.I made that part in grails.If i click on the particular file i want download that file.I dont know how to make that part.I did a google search.But i cannot do that.

My code is

```
 <g:each in="${fileList}" var="filename" status="i">
    ${filename}
   <!-- Codes to make a file downloadable-->
  </g:each>
```

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396677/grails-file-download">This will help</a>

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the right headers so that the browser knows its a file that it needs to download. I'm not sure how to do that in grails. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519