# Grails sending file then delete afterwards

Tags: java, grails

I'm sending a file using the response << file.newInputStream (similar to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396677/grails-file-download), but I want to delete this file afterwards. However, when I call delete on this file, it doesn't delete it. I'm quite sure it's because the file is still in use (streaming). How an I check this and then delete.

```
    def tempfile = new File(filename)
    if (tempfile) {
       response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
       response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${tempfile.getName()}")
       response.outputStream << tempfile.newInputStream()
    } else {
       renderErrorMsg("ERROR: Cannot open/find file - ${filename}.")
    }
    tempfile.delete()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing the input stream. Change

```
response.outputStream << tempfile.newInputStream()
```

To

```
tempfile.withInputStream { response.outputStream << it }
```

The latter will ensure the stream is closed. Also you may want to delete the file in a finally block in case an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks! I did have it in a try-catch but want to simplify the sample code. Do you have a link where this is explained in more detail?